# Gulf stream weakening affects on both ends of the system - Europe and Carribean

Tags: climate-change, oceanography, climate-models

There have been reports about the Gulf Stream weakening. Everything I have read about this concentrates on the (possibly substantial) cooling this would cause in Europe. 
If this weakening occurs, presumably there will be much less heat transported away from the southern end of the Gulf Stream causing warming in the Atlantic and Caribbean. Has any modelling been done to indicate what the consequences of this are likely to be?

Comment: If you look at a globe (not a Mercator map), the South end is much wider so the warming effect would be spread out. (My mental modelling.)